# SVG image won't preserve its aspect ratio with max width / height set

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG image with a defined width and height:

```
<svg width="1280" height="1920"> ... </svg>
```

I want it to keep its aspect ratio *however* also respect the following rules so it always fit the viewport:

```
max-width: 100vw;
max-height: 100vh;
```

It works well with a basic image or a canvas element, however doesn't work with SVG images. Any ideas? I'd hate to add additional markup to accomplish this.

```css
svg {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1280" height="1920"></svg>
```

PS: SVG image can be any width / height, so it's not that width is always less than height. It can be the other way around.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: SVG documents use virtual unit, width and height attributes belong to HTML not SVG,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to use a `viewBox` - as a since-deleted answer suggested.
2. You are being misled about what's happening because you are using `background-color: green` on the `<svg>`.

SVGs behave differently from bitmap images like PNGs.  The `<svg>` can grow to the size of the container, but the contents of the SVG will be scaled to fit that container.

Example

```css
svg {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280 1920">
  <rect width="1280" height="1920" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

To control how the contents are scaled, you can use the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

Comment: I didn't know this strange behavior. great job man.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. I did have the `viewBox` defined, however was completely misled by the background color of the SVG element as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, I don't think you can use pixel to resize SVG file.

Refer to this article: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: someone answered this question before and it is marked as accepted, therefore this isnt necessary anymore since it doesnt really help. Once you earn enough reputation you can comment instead

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

to your CSS. That way, the width will adjust itself when the height is restricted by `max-height` and vice versa.